# connect UHF RFID reader with raspberry pi 3 using rasberian

Tags: raspbian, linux, i2c, rfid

i have  a [UHF RFID](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/uhf-rfid-passive-card-reader-with-8dBi-antenna-built-in-read-rang-6-8m-depend-on/32675366203.html) i am using raspberian os . i connected the tx rx and gnd to raspberry pi . but i dont know how to read a tag. and there is no sdk available for linux platform . can anyone guide me how to use it. i found a tutorial but it was done using windows 10 iot . But i have to do it with raspberian os only.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the info available on the link you provided, I would use the RS232 port of the RFID reader.

If the RFID device has real RS232, you need a voltage level translator between the standard RS232 voltages and the Raspberry 3.3V GPIO, like this one:
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11189

RS232 level translation is explained in this article (here they convert it to 5V, but theory is the same):
https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/215

To experiment with the RFID device, I would first connect it to a PC (if it has no RS232 port, you can use an USB RS232 converter), and see what strings it sends when an RFID card is read.

When you are familiar with the message formats, you can write e.g. a python script to RPi to parse the serial port messages, and do necessary actions.